# Number of possible combinations for k-clustering of a set of points

Tags: math, cluster-analysis, combinations

I have a set of n points. I want to partition them into k clusters. I am trying to figure out how many combinations of such partitioning exists in this case.

Answer (score 1):

[Number of partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions) of set size n into k non-empty subsets is equal to [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Explicit formula is

```
S2(n, k) =  1/k! * Sum(i=0..k)[(-1)^i * C(k,i) * (k - i)^n]
```

(also look at recurrence relation as more reliable method to calculate S2())

Numbers rise fast. For example, `S2(4,3) = 6; S2(10,5)=42525`